# Why use two NICs, one external facing and the other internal facing?

Tags: ethernet, nat, interface

As the question implies, why use two NICs, one external facing and the other internal facing when one would suffice for both functions using NAT.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you referring to hosts, firewalls, routers, or what?

Comment: servers/hosts in general. For example when someone would setup a VPN connection, i noticed he used an internal and external facing virtualized adapter (VMNet4, VMNet5 etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to think about is traffic competing for the bandwidth resources of a single Interface. This may be less important for a end-user PC, but it could be very important for a server, firewall, or router.

It is less likely, but not unheard of, for an end-user PC to saturate a single network interface. More likely is that servers, firewall, routers, etc., will saturate a single network interface. For instance, it used to be common practice to use a router-on-a-stick to route between subnets, but that limited the bandwidth on each of the VLANs in the trunk. The modern approach is to move the routing down to a layer-3 switch which can have multiple layer-2 inputs, spreading the load to individual VLAN interfaces or multiple trunk ports.

NICs are relatively inexpensive so it is a cheap solution to use different NICs for different things on PCs and servers, albeit more expensive on fixed devices like firewalls and routers.

Answer (score 3):

> why use two NICs, one external facing and the other internal facing when one would suffice for both functions using NAT

Let me start by saying that this is thinking backwards a bit. Why would you use NAT when a better solution is available? NAT is a band aid. An ugly "temporary" solution to a problem.

NAT is generally to be avoided whenever possible. It does little good, takes resources, increases latency, and often creates problems.

> Why use two NICs, one external facing and the other internal facing?

For this, there are many specific reasons, but they can be summed up as segregation/isolation for security and/or performance reasons.

### A few examples:

- Dedicated NICs for normal and management traffic - separate NICs make this easy to configure and firewall, both on the server and on the network. Further, if the server is under a DoS type of attack on the normal NIC, you may still have access on the management NIC.
- Dedicated NIC for network based backups/snapshots - this allows the backups to utilize the full capability of the NIC performance without affecting any normal traffic to/from the server.
- Dedicated NIC for access to an isolated network - imagine you have a network of "insecure" devices (e.g. SCADA devices) and you want them isolated from any access (no gateway or access to any other network resource). The management server can be configured with a NIC to communicate with this isolated network (pull data, push configs, etc) and another NIC for access to the server which may provide reporting, alerting or other services.